# Calculated column that populates date based on subtracting 6 hours from source column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to create a calculated column that populates with a date based on subtracting 6 hours from each datetime value in the Scan_Date column.  I've been having a surprisingly hard time getting this done.

[image]

I tried using a measure and DAX but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DAX:

```
Column = [Scan_Date] - 6/24
```

*or*

```
Column = [Scan_Date] - Time(6,0,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
 = [Scan_Date]-#duration(0,6,0,0)
```